# Set alert to an empty textfield

Tags: javascript, text, string

I need a function to send an alert and then returns if a text field is left empty. my js list with the text fields is:

```
var filterList = [{name: "filterStartTime", type: "date", label: "Alguskuupäev"},
                  {name: "filterEndTime", type: "date", label: "Lõppkuupäev"},
                  {name: "filterDoctorCode", type: "text", label: "Dokumendi koostaja arstikood", upper:true},
                  {name: "filterDoctorSpecialityCode", type: "select", label: "Dokumendi koostaja erialakood", upper:true},
                  {name: "filterDocIdAndOid", type: "sub", label: "Dokumendi identifikaator", sub: [
                      {name: "filterDocIdOid",  type: "text", label: "OID", size: 35, noCheckbox: true},
                      {name: "filterDocId",     type: "text", label: "ID", noCheckbox: true}],
                      noCheckbox: false
                  },
                  {name: "filterCompanyCode", type: "text", label: "Koostaja asutuse registrikood"},
                  {name: "filterDocumentType", type: "select", label: "Dokumendi tüüp"}
                ];
```

my jsp file where they are called is:

```
String filterDoctorCode = request.getParameter("filterDoctorCode");
            if(filterDoctorCode != null) filterDoctorCode = filterDoctorCode.trim();

            String filterDoctorSpecialityCode = request.getParameter("filterDoctorSpecialityCode");
            if(filterDoctorSpecialityCode != null) filterDoctorSpecialityCode = filterDoctorSpecialityCode.trim();

            String filterDocIdOid = request.getParameter("filterDocIdOid");
            if(filterDocIdOid != null) filterDocIdOid = filterDocIdOid.trim();
            String filterDocId = request.getParameter("filterDocId");
            if(filterDocId != null) filterDocId = filterDocId.trim();

            String filterCompanyCode = request.getParameter("filterCompanyCode");
            if(filterCompanyCode != null) filterCompanyCode = filterCompanyCode.trim();

            if(statusCode == null) statusCode = "deliveredResponse";
            dlPatDocs.setProcedure(statusCode, filterDoctorCode, filterStartTime, filterEndTime, filterDocIdOid, filterDocId, filterCompanyCode, filterDoctorSpecialityCode);


            sendId = dlPatDocs.send();
```

So I know it's hard to understand with my fauklty description but I hope someone understood and can help.

in the JS, I think I need to add the alert in here:

```
    else if(filterList[i].type == "text"){
        if (!filterList[i].size) filterList[i].size = 20;
        filterInnerHtml += "<input type=\"text\" id=\"" + filterList[i].name + "_input\" ";
        if (filterList[i].upper) filterInnerHtml += " onchange='javascript:fieldValToUpperCase(this);' "
        filterInnerHtml += " class=\"txt_left\" value=\"\" maxlength=\""+ filterList[i].size + "\" size=\""+ filterList[i].size + "\" />";
    }
```

but I'm not exactly sure...

Sorry, I forgot to mention that the list is called in third file:

```
<td>
                <!-- Will be built by JS in FilterBank.js#addFilterBank() -->
                <div id = "filtripank"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="images/progress.gif" alt="" border="0" id="progressIndicator" style="display:none" />

                <input type="button" class="button" value="Saada päring" onClick="javascript:startDocumentListUpdate()" id="updateButton" />
            </td>
```

so I need that when I click on "updateButton" it checks wether the text value is empty and if it is, it sends back a message and doesnt do the onClick "javascript:startDocumentListUpdate()".....Hope it made sense

Comment: Do you have jQuery loaded in your page ?

Comment: yes, its loaded allright

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a live sample to check empty text fields:

```js
var filterList = [{name: "filterStartTime", type: "date", label: "Alguskuupäev"},
                  {name: "filterEndTime", type: "date", label: "Lõppkuupäev"},
                  {name: "filterDoctorCode", type: "text", label: "Dokumendi koostaja arstikood", upper:true},
                  {name: "filterDoctorSpecialityCode", type: "select", label: "Dokumendi koostaja erialakood", upper:true},
                  {name: "filterDocIdAndOid", type: "sub", label: "Dokumendi identifikaator", sub: [
                      {name: "filterDocIdOid",  type: "text", label: "OID", size: 35, noCheckbox: true},
                      {name: "filterDocId",     type: "text", label: "ID", noCheckbox: true}],
                      noCheckbox: false
                  },
                  {name: "filterCompanyCode", type: "text", label: "Koostaja asutuse registrikood"},
                  {name: "filterDocumentType", type: "select", label: "Dokumendi tüüp"}
                ];

function checkEmpty(list) {
  var i;
  for (i in list) {
    if (list[i].type == "text") {
      var name = list[i].name;
      if ($("input[name=" + name + "]").val() == "") {
        alert(name + " is empty !");
      }
    }
    if (list[i].sub) {
      checkEmpty(list[i].sub);
    }
  }
}

$(function () {
  $("button").click(function () {
    checkEmpty(filterList);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
filterDoctorCode: <input type="text" name="filterDoctorCode"/><br/>
filterDocIdOid: <input type="text" name="filterDocIdOid"/><br/>
filterDocId: <input type="text" name="filterDocId"/><br/>
filterCompanyCode: <input type="text" name="filterCompanyCode"/><br/>
<button>check empty</button>
```

Comment: I forgot a thing, I updated my question...

Comment: It is not clear and I have no many time. I have try to help you with a `check for empty text input` function, like you subject title `Set alert to an empty textfield` …

Answer (score 0):

inout test field:

```
  <input type="text" name="checking" id="checking" onblur="checkTextField(this);" />
```

And javascript are used for check is empty :

```
function checkTextField(field) {
    if (field.value == '') {
        alert("Field is empty");
    }
}
```